# javascript forEach - same code acts differently on chrome windows / IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, foreach, ecmascript-6

```
let { classList } = document.body;

classList.forEach((className) => {
    if (className.startsWith('somePrefix')) {
        classList.remove(className);
    }
});
```

The above code will run just fine on non-IOS browsers, but will fail with:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

on IOS browsers (tested on **iphone 6s IOS 10 Safari and Chrome**), in case one class or more is removed.

It happens because on non-IOS browsers, once you remove an element during iteration it will know to reduce the number of iterations by 1, whereas on IOS it'll try to continue with the original number of iterations with `undefineds`.

I'm not looking for a solution (very easy to solve) but for an explanation of **why** it happens, what is implemented differently on IOS and how? (could be `forEach`, `classList.remove`, etc)

Thanks.

Comment: @Xufox - edited

Comment: Sounds like you know *why* it happens too. Sounds like polyfill behaviour, does iOS support `classList` natively? If so, it's a bug, because `classList` is a live binding

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I know **what** happens but not **why**, IOS safari does support `classList` according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)